# I don't understand the behavior of this below code. Can someone help me here

Tags: python, metaclass

```
class A(type):
    _l = []
    def __call__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        if len(cls._l)<=5:
            cls._l.append(super().__call__(*args,**kwargs))
        else:
            return cls._l

class B(metaclass=A):
    pass


#testing starts

a=B()
a1=B()

assert a is a1
```

the above statement succeeds.But as per my understanding it should not succeed. as two instances of the same class should share different memory locations.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What did your interpreter claim `a` and `a1` _are_? What happened when you stepped through it in `pdb`?

Comment: If I check the contents of the list that is appended with each instance creation,I see [<__main__.B at 0x221e72462e8>, <__main__.B at 0x221e7246748>]  . So we have 2 memeory locations for 2 instances.Then a is a1 should be False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a broken, in several places, attempt to implementa limit of 5 instances for a given class, just like a singleton is a limit of one instance for a given class.

Moreover, the testing is broken as well.

The thing is that whenever you try to instantiate a class in Python, it is no different than calling any other object: the `__call__` method is run in the class's class - that is, its metaclass. Ordinarily, the metaclass's `__call__` is responsible for calling the class' `__new__` and `__init__` method - and that is done when `super().__call__` is invoked in the example above. The value returned by `__call__` is then used as the new instance - and there is what is perhaps the most gross error above: in the first 5 times `A.__call__` runs, it returns `None`.

So None is assigned both to `a` and to `a1`, and None is a singleton - that is why your assertion works.

Now, if one is to  fix that  and return the newly created instance whenever `len(l) < 5`, that would restrict the total number of  instances for all classes that have `A` as  a metaclass, not just five instances of `B`. Thatis because to work per class, the `_l` attribute should be located in the class themselves - the way the code is set above, it will be retrieved from the class'class - which is `A._l` - (unless one explicitly creates a `_l` attribute in B and other classes) .

And finally, there is no mechanism to provide a round-robin of the limited created instances on the code above, which is what one can imagine as a thing that could have some utility - instead of selecting an instance, the list with all created instances is returned in raw.

So, before posting a working version of this, let's get one thing straight: you ask

> two instances of the same class should share different memory
>   locations.

Yes - but what actually creates the two different isntances is `type.__call__`. The `A.__call__` there won't be calling this everytime, and whatever object it returns will be used in place of the new instance. If it returns a pre-existing object, that is what the caller code gets.

Rewording it so there are no doubts:  instantiating classes is no different than calling any other object in Python: the associated object's `__call__` is run and returns a value.

Now, if the idea is to have a limit of instances of classes, and balance the instances being retrieved, the metaclass code could be so:

```
MAX_INSTANCES = 5

class A(type):

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        cls._instances = instances = getattr(cls, "_instances", [])
        cls._index = getattr(cls, "_index", -1)
        if len(instances) < MAX_INSTANCES:
            # Actually creates a new instance:
            instance = super().__call__(cls, *args, **kw)
            instances.append(instance)
        cls._index = (cls._index + 1) % MAX_INSTANCES
        return cls._instances[cls._index]


class B(metaclass=A):
    pass

b_list = [B() for B in range(MAX_INSTANCES * 2)]

for i in range(MAX_INSTANCES):
    assert b_list[i] is b_list[i + MAX_INSTANCES]
    for j in range(1, MAX_INSTANCES):
        assert b_list[i] is not b_list[i + j]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation . It really helped.